# Bloomberg Desktop Api v3 Python 2.7 add historical data to a list

Tags: python, python-2.7, bloomberg

I have searched for the answer but unfortunately I have not been able to find it for the 'new' APIv3 that supports Python 2.7.

Full disclosure, I am very new to Python.

I am able to establish a connection with Bloomberg and query historical data with the included example(SimpleHistoryExample.py), however I am having trouble adding it to a simple list. It prints out the data in what looks like jagged lists:

```
HistoricalDataResponse = {
securityData = {
    security = "IBM US Equity"
    eidData[] = {
    }
    sequenceNumber = 0
    fieldExceptions[] = {
    }
    fieldData[] = {
        fieldData = {
            date = 2006-01-31
            PX_LAST = 81.300000
            OPEN = 82.450000
        }
        fieldData = {
            date = 2006-02-28
            PX_LAST = 80.240000
            OPEN = 80.900000
        }
    ETC......
```

All I am trying to do is query ex. "BAC US EQUITY" and get "PX_LAST" from DATE1 to DATE2 into a list ex.listHistPrices which I then can slice and dice however I see fit.

Unfortunately I can't find any documentation for the Python SDK and only examples.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you get if you `print type(response)`. Also, you could try casting it as a list, e.g. `my_list = list(response)`.

Comment: Looks like a JSON to me.

Comment: This is the code https://github.com/fengxia41103/hime/blob/master/blpapi-3.5.2/examples/SimpleHistoryExample.py  "print type(response)" returns nothing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the exact code I need on github!

https://github.com/kyuni22/pybbg/blob/master/pybbg/pybbg_k.py

The only other thing needed was to get and install Pandas with the dependencies

Answer (score 0):

i use a 2-step approach for this:

1. store the data from bberg in a bottomless `defaultdict`:

   `def dd():
       return defaultdict(dd)`
2. convert that to a `pandas DataFrame` for easier access using `from_dict`

note, this will use a lot of memory on larger datasets.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I keep on trying to store the 'msg' on line 74 but I have a feeling I am doing something fundamentally wrong. I declare defaultdict outside and then assign it msg but when I go to print it it returns empty "{}". Here is the code (the original example from bb): https://github.com/fengxia41103/hime/blob/master/blpapi-3.5.2/examples/SimpleHistoryExample.py

Comment: basically you need to iterate over the msg itself using calls like `getElement` and `getValue` to assign things to the `defaultdict`. (e.g. `d[field] = msg.getElement(field)`). http://www.openbloomberg.com/content/uploads/sites/2/2012/03/blpapi-developers-guide.pdf has some good examples

Comment: Thanks, you put me on the right track and I was able to find prewritten code that did exactly what I wanted

Comment: you got it, glad you found a solution.